# Where do I get steady technical content writing work?

Tags: technical-writing

I am an electronics engineer with UG and PG degrees. Post qualification, I have 9 years of experience in my field. For the past three years I have been freelancing in technical content writing. Up to now, it has been an on and off matter for me.

I want to create a steady source of secondary income through freelancing.

Where can I get regular assignments? I have tried various job boards and pitched to a lot of websites for the past year. No success yet. I have good online samples from my sporadic writing stints.

Answer (score 1):

### It seems like there are two methods of growing a service business: marketing and reach

Your reach can be extended by working with temping companies. It seems like companies will bring on extra help for technical writing on a project-by-project basis.  I'd imagine since you have a full-time job, that a temp agency might present challenges

Social media and web pages are cost-effective marketing tools. For creative writing, there are many people publishing free content on how to write novels, short stories, or non-fiction pieces. I've never seen any content on writing effective technical documentation. Maybe that represents untapped potential. By providing free content that provides solid advice on creating effective technical content you could expand your pool of opportunity -- resulting in more freelance work